# Get substring from Start Index to End Index

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on this for two hours but no luck, always the *"Bad substitution"* error.

What I want to make (.sh script):
Read from file (names), then I'd like to substitute this name with substring of the given name by the offset and lenght which are the script arguments ($1 = offset, $2 = lenght).

It should work like this (I think) : `new_user=${user:$1:$2}`
-> where user is read from .txt (in while loop) and $1 and $2 are arguments of this .sc

I've highlighted the important part:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
touch postopek.log
while IFS="," read fullName userName passwordLarge
do
 pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt(&ARGV[0], "password")' $passwordLarge)
 new_up=${fullName:$1:$2} # important line
 sudo useradd -m -p $pass -d /home/$new_up -s /bin/bash $new_up
 [ $? -eq 0] && echo "Made something bla bla not important..." >> postopek.log
 sudo mkdir /home/$new_up/gradivo
 sudo cp -r /home/administrator/vaje/* /home/$new_up/gradivo
 sudo chown -R $new_up:$new_up /home/$new_up/gradivo
done < /home/administrator/seznam.txt
```

Comment: @administrator:  sh ustvari.sh 3 5

/// If you need .txt file, here it is: http://pastebin.com/c23AaE4k

Comment: and the $1 and $2 arguments are numbers? Did you try running you script with the `set -vx` debugging options? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sh shell you are running the script with is probably not bash, try running it like

```
bash ustvari.sh 3 5
```

or just

```
/path/to/ustvari.sh 3 5
```

since your [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) points to bash anyway.

`${parameter:offset:length}` is not specified by POSIX, thus if your `/bin/sh` is a shell which does not support the substring syntax, you get the `Bad substitution` error you encountered, for example:

```
$ dash
$ echo ${foo:0:1}
dash: 1: Bad substitution
```